# Angular 5 How to affect ngClass in main HTML from a component?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular2-directives, angular5

I'm trying to change button's style by clicking other button in a different component.

Right now, I have a main html page and there's an angular component loaded on page using angular selector `<component1></component1>`

Here's main html file containing the component:

```
                  <button id="button01" 
                  tappable>
                     <ion-icon name="square" [ngClass]="Btn1"></ion-icon>
                   </button>                                          

                  <button id="button02" 
                  tappable>
                     <ion-icon name="square" [ngClass]="Btn2"></ion-icon>
                   </button>
```

and here's my component HTML file. It has a button that is trying to change that Btn1 and Btn2 style to button-active3 class.

```
<button id="componentbutton" tappable (click)="Btn1='button-active3'; 
  Btn2='button-inactive';">Change Color!</button>
```

button-active3 and button-inactive are styles classes of button in my SCSS file.

I found this configuration doesn't trigger component's button to change styles of buttons in the main html file.

How can I make this work?

If I put that component's button inside the main HTML file, it will work fine.. but I think it doesn't work because now the button is in a component and the component can't access to ngClass of main HTML file.

Please help. If there's a way to work around it, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would create a service and use that to communicate between your main page and the component.

Comment: Hi David, yes. I have tried.. but I wonder how to execute Btn1='button-active3' as a function in service. It didn't work. Is it possible for you to show me an example? thanks a lot!

Comment: so basically you want a nested(child) components click event to change parents html class by clicking a button from child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For communication between child and parent you can use angular's EventEmitter property which triggers an event on some action using the @Output decorator and the parent binds to that event property and reacts to those events:

Child component html:

```
<button id="componentbutton" tappable (click)="someFunction()">Change Color!</button> // you can pass paramters inside the function if you want to trigger an event by passing some values to parent
```

Child ts:

```
@Output() changeClass: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(); //import output from @angular/core

someFunction() {
  this.changeClass.emit();
}
```

Parent html:

```
<componentName (changeClass)="anotherFn($event)"></componentName>
```

Parent ts:

```
anotherFn(){
  this.Btn1 ='button-active3';
  this.Btn2 ='button-inactive';
}
```

then you can easily bind Btn1 and Btn2 anywhere you want and you will get the classes applied

```
<ion-icon name="square" [ngClass]="Btn1"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="square" [ngClass]="Btn2"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this shortly... greatly appreciated your help.

Comment: Actually, it's working now.. sorry my bad. Thanks a lot! I had to declare btn1 and btn2 as string on parent ts..

Comment: Yes they need to be declared as string so that you can directly pass your desired class name to ngClass